# Scanner has no next line although there is something in the file

Tags: java, file

I tried to scan a text file and rewrite it with one change. However, the scanner does not have a new line, although there is already something in the text file. What could be the reason?

```
public class ThemeStatus {

public void statusChanger(String subject, String name) {
    
    PrintWriter fileWriter = null;
    File themeFile = new File("FüFolder/Themenübersicht/" + subject + "/Settings.txt");
    Scanner fileScanner = null;
    
    try {
        fileWriter = new PrintWriter(themeFile);        
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    try {
        fileScanner = new Scanner(themeFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    System.out.println(fileScanner.hasNextLine());
    if(fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
            if(line.contains("CurrentTheme")) {
                fileWriter.println("CurrentTheme = " + name);
            }
            else {
                fileWriter.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        fileWriter.println("CurrentTheme = " + name);
    }   
    fileWriter.close();
}
```

Comment: [Your `PrintWriter` truncates the file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.File))

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know a way to prevent this?

Comment: Don't write to the same file you're reading from.

Comment: You could take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html